# Plot data.table in two colors

Tags: r, plot, colors, data.table

I have a very large data.table, and I want to plot a sample of the values in the columns against each other, colored according to a 0-1 third column.

This is the code making the black plots. I want it colored according to the column y in my data.table (0=blue, 1=red).

```
plot(as.data.frame(mydata)[sample(1:nrow(mydata),10000),8:16])
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: See `pairs()` function, and for colours use `ifelse(x==0,"red","blue")`

Comment: Thank you. The following gave me the plot I wanted: `
sample_to_plot = sample(1:nrow(dt),10000)
windows()
pairs(dt[sample_to_plot,8:16], main = "plots", pch = 20, col = alpha(ifelse(dt[sample_to_plot,7]==0,"blue","red"),0.3))
`

Comment: Great, post it as an answer in below **Your Answer** box.

Answer (score 1):

The following gave the the plot I wanted

```
sample_to_plot = sample(1:nrow(dt),10000)
windows() 
pairs(dt[sample_to_plot,8:16], main = "plots", pch = 20, col = alpha(ifelse(dt[sample_to_plot,7]==0,"blue","red"),0.3))
```